# can't encrypt image withe RSA

Tags: java, image, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt BMP image withe RSA in java,it's supposed to create the encrypted and decrypted images.

Ok so after reading the comments and learned that it is not safe to use RSA alone;I edit my Question. and tryd Java Cryptography but cipher.doFinal() don't accepted  a data  longer than 245 bytes

```
    File bmpFile = new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py\\6.bmp");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bmpFile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos );
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    byte[] b1=new byte[b.length];   

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    cipher.update(b);
    b1 = cipher.doFinal();
    bmpFile=new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py\\66.bmp");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(bmpFile);
    fos.write(b1);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

and it give :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2048)
```

most of my image are 198x135
i found here in stack onverflow that

```
The RSA algorithm can only encrypt data that has a maximum byte length of the RSA key length in bits divided with eight minus eleven padding bytes, i.e. number of maximum bytes = key length in bits / 8 - 11.
```

and said that you have to encrypt the data with symmetric key and encrypt the symmetric key with rsa.
but i whent to encrypt the data with RSA.

Comment: If you want to encrypt with RSA, why don't you use the built-in [`javax.crypto.Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) to do it? Would likely be a lot faster than what you're doing.

Comment: it's part of my School Project

Comment: (1) RSA cryptograms are the size of the modulus, in your case 2048 or 2047 bits; pixels in Java `BufferedImage` are 24 bits. 2048 or 2047 does not fit in 24. (2) 'Textbook' (unpadded) RSA is insecure, especially for small plaintexts like yours; this is explained in wikipedia, which I guess you didn't read, and many times on crypto.SX and security.SX. Using d directly is also inefficient; see the same sources. (3) If you have a shared symmetric key, it makes no sense to use it to wrap RSA, just use it for the data (4) but not RC4, it's partly broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And i went to ask,i have to send the encrypting image to Other pc but the problem is that p,q are random

Asymmetric encryption means encrypting for a specific target (public key).

So the steps would be:

- the receiver creates its <del>private key (p, q, e) and public key (N, d)</del> private key (p, q, d) and public key (N, e)
- the receiver sends its public key to the sender
- sender uses the public key to encrypt the message
- receiver can use its private key to decrypt the data

So if you want to use RSA to encrypt any data, the parameters are random for the target receiver, but given for the sender.

> do i have to encrypt theme with Symmetric algorithm like RC4 and send theme with the image

As you already may find out, RSA operations are pretty slow. So common way to use RSA is *hybrid encryption* - encrypting data with a random symmetric encryption key and use RSA to encrypt only the random key.

> image.setRGB(i, j,pixels[i][j].intValue());

This won't work. Encryption of any data will have length of the key length. Effectively you need 1024 bit for each image pixel in your case. Trimming the bigint to the intValue you are loosing information.

That's why the (already mentioned) hybrid encryption is used

> it's part of my School Project

If you will use RSA for real life projects:

- *Textbook RSA* has several weaknesses, to make the solution secure, you need to use a padding, common standards are pkcs#1 v1.5 or OAEP padding
- In reality you should use the default crypto library which is much faster and resilient against side-channel attacks

Comment: @kelaka indeed a typo, thanx, fixed

Comment: pkcs#v1.5 padding should no longer be used for new development and schould be changed to OAEP wherever possible (for the cryptographic reason see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47436/how-much-safer-is-rsa-oaep-compared-to-rsa-with-pkcs1-v1-5-padding )